# 2 same value on gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

hello i am currently having search button on my form and i want to search is between 2 date and i want to have a alert message if i have 2 same record on other column this is my code for now

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlData = new SqlDataAdapter("DateFilter", sqlCon);
        sqlData.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlData.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", TxtFromDate.Text);
        sqlData.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date2", TxtToDate.Text);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        sqlData.Fill(dtbl);
        sqlCon.Close();
        Gridview1.DataSource = dtbl;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
        Gridview1.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
        Gridview1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```

Comment: Do you want a message box to pop up or do you want the rows/columns in the gridview to be highlighted somehow? Also, can we see the sql statement that you are running?

Comment: <<have a alert message if i have 2 same record on other column>> --- Gee, what on earth does that mean? Say your search returns 10 rows. What do you mean by same record on some other column? A column is not a record??? And what other columns you talking about???

Comment: @Mifo this is my sql statement select *
   FROM
   FinishedGood
   Where CreatedDate between '2022-02-28' and '2022-03-08' order by CreatedDate
i want to have a highlighted rows/columns

Comment: @JohnWick are you looking at values of two columns in a single row being equal or two or more consecutive rows that have the same value in a particular column?

Comment: But what is to be highlighted and based on what? So if 3 rows match and are returned - say with that same start and end dates, what is to be highlighted? The grid is assumed to only have rows that match your criteria - so we fill grid with data, but now what rows are to be highlighted based on what criteria or value? If you can't explain this then I suggest you try cooking school or maybe even truck driving school, but you are demonstrating that software clearly not your future if you can't explain what you are looking for here. We have 2 people here confused - and I've been at this 25 years

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard decrypting your question. It seems you have an existing SQL result in your `DataGridView` and then want to check via a button if there are multiple entries with the same "CreatedDate" value.

(1) You should use defined objects in order to be able to work with object items instead of `DataTable` row/column indexes which is a hassle.

Therefore you need to define your object, map your `DataTable` rows as objects items in a collection (here: a simple `List<>`) and then set this collection to your `DataGridView.DataSource`, e.g.:

```
// define single object
public class FinishedGood {
  public int      ID          { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
  ...
}

// define object collection
public class FinishedGoods : List<FinishedGood> { }

// execute your existing SQL query and fill the DataTable
...

// convert DataTable to FinishedGoods
FinishedGoods finishedGoods = new FinishedGoods();
foreach (DataRow row in dtbl.Rows) {
  finishedGoods.Add(new FinishedGood() {
    ID          = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"]),
    CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse(row["CreatedDate"].ToString());,
    ...
  });
}

// set the collection as datasource
gv.DataSource = finishedGoods;
```

(2) Now, you can check the `DataSource` for duplicates via Linq:

```
using System.Linq;

private HashSet<FinishedGood> CheckForDuplicateCreatedDates() {
  HashSet<FinishedGood> result = new HashSet<FinishedGood>();

  // collect all createdDates
  HashSet<DateTime> createdDates = new HashSet<DateTime>();
  foreach (FinishedGood finishedGood in gv.DataSource){
    if (!createdDates.Contains(finishedGood.createdDate)) {
      createdDates.Add(finishedGood.createdDate);
    }
  }

  // loop through all createdDates
  foreach (DateTime createdDate in createdDates) {
    // check if there are more than 2 entries with the createdDate in your DataSource
    if (gv.DataSource.Count(x => x.CreatedDate == createdDate) > 2) {
      // add those entries to your duplicate result list
      foreach (FinishedGood finishedGood in gv.DataSource.Where(x => x.CreatedDate == createdDate)) {
        result.Add(finishedGood);
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

(3) To show the alert popup, you can use [`MessageBox.Show()`](https://thedeveloperblog.com/c-sharp/messagebox-show).

(4) To highlight the corresponding rows in the `DataGridview`, you can use the result of (2) to find the corresponding row indexes and then adjust their `DefaultCellStyle`.

The button click would look something like this:

```
private void buttonCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // get duplicates
  HashSet<FinishedGood> duplicates = CheckForDuplicateCreatedDates();

  if (duplicates.Count() > 0) {
    // show alert popup
    MessageBox.Show("Duplicates found");

    // highlight the corresponding rows
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gv.Rows) {
      if (duplicates.Contains((row.DataBoundItem as FinishedGood))) {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
      }
    }
  }
}
```